# Working with ASP.Net MasterPage

Tags: asp.net

im new with ASP.Net, i defined a MasterPage for my WebSite and 3 Content-Pages, Default, Login and Register. bei Debugging, the Masterpage renderd the DefaultPage. what i want is that the Masterpage should bei  first load to render the LoginPage not the defaultPage. any help!

Comment: What do you mean by `first load to render exactly`? Do you want Browser to show `Login` page first when you load you website instead of `Default`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just right click on your login.aspx and set it as the start up page..

Comment: no ... he should right click the login page and set as start up page. No the master page <_<